# where is custom field stored in database?

Tags: magento2, custom-field

I have added a custom field in Magento 2, the *Attribute Code* is **product_custom_type** as shown in screen-shot. But where is this custom field stored in the database? I've ran a query to search all tables by field name **product_custom_type**, and I couldn't find it. Does this `attribute_code` has another name as the field name in the database?

[image]

Comment: you can check it inside eav_attribute table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find It from `eav_attribute` table. All the attribute created for

1. catalog_product
2. customer
3. customer_address
4. catalog_category

saved in this table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me out. If I want to add this Attribute to the table **sales_order_item** table, do I need to make a module to make this happen, or is there another way to do it? thanks.

Comment: Why you want to add this attribute in sales_order_item ?

Comment: It's because I have bought a Magento 2 Module - Export Order Tool. This module only allow me to choose from the Attribute  **prudct_type**, which is a Magento default field, that find in table  _sales_order_item_. But I want to use my own Attribute **product_custom_type** instead. And to do that, I need to add this custom Attribute in the table _sales_order_item_, according to the support team where I bought the module from.